# Tensorflow Optimizer On Multi-valued Tensor

Tags: tensorflow

By mistake I forgot to reduce the mean of the output from the cross entropy before I fed it as the loss, but the training ran anyways and produced reasonable results.

Now I'm wondering if what I did:

```
loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=logits, name='cross_entropy_per_example')
op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)
```

Is the same as:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=logits, name='cross_entropy_per_example'))
op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)
```

I was under the impression that the optimization of the cost function required a single value tensor, but I'm confused why the training ran despite passing a tensor with more than one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.gradients` (and therefore most higher-level interfaces to it, including `Optimizer`s) implicitly sums whatever you're differentiating. `tf.gradients` will only compute gradients with respect to a scalar. There is some mention of this in the [`tf.gradients` documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients).

So in your case it's just off by whatever `reduce_mean` was dividing by.

Comment: Aha, so it is pretty similar. Am I right to assume loss would be much greater without tf.reduce_mean?

Comment: The implicit reduce_sum version will just multiply your learning rate by your batch size when compared to reduce_mean, so probably yes unless the batch size is very small.